# Changing font colour on alternate rows in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I'm looking for a way to change the font colour on alternate rows within a datagrid. e.g. normal row would be green and the alternate row would be blue.

I can change either by using

- me.datagrid.Styles.Row.Forcolour
- me.datagrid.Styles.AlternatingRow.Forcolour

The problem is that I am having trouble using both of them together as I need to manipulate both colours. I have created a HtmlRowPrepared event and have been setting them there, however, If I set the Row.Forcolour first, it will over ride the AlternatingRow.Forcolour and vice versa.

This needs to be done via SEVER SIDE code only as the colour choices are held in the database.

If you could help I would be very grateful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

A GridView has style attributes which you can declare in the HTML.

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server">
    <AlternatingRowStyle  BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" CssClass="alternating-row" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="row" />
</asp:GridView>
```

In these tags you can declare all you need, also adding a CssClass to each. I would suggest using the CssClass only, and then updating the styles in your stylesheet. This is better for updating styles in the future.

Comment: it needs to be dynamic and via server side code as the style options are held in a database

Comment: My bad, I was trying to manipulate the whole grid view control within an event that was designed to only effect a single row. to fix the problem, I used both of the attributes within the on load event and it solved my problem.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please paste some code so that we can understand how you are doing this
well you can set these values aspx page where you define your control

```
     <ItemStyle  ForeColor="Green"/>
     <AlternatingItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
```

I m sure this will work and if it doesnt please paste your code for better understanding

Comment: I need to do this via server side code as everything is held in the database

Comment: My bad, I was trying to manipulate the whole grid view control within an event that was designed to only effect a single row. to fix the problem, I used both of the attributes within the on load event and it solved my problem.

Thanks for your help

Comment: ItemStyle/AlternatingItemStyle should be RowStyle/AlternatingRowStyle if it is a GridView as the Question says, but then in the content of the question it refers to DataGrid